# Error with fnmatch() in python (Object has no attribute replace)

Tags: python

For some reason I keep getting the following error when I run the `fnmatch` function.

> Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

It works when I try it with a single link, but doesn't work when I loop through an array and try to match every link in the array.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = requests.get("https://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/2010_elections_governor_map.html").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'html.parser')

all_links = [link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a')]
matched_links = [fnmatch(link, pattern) for link in all_links]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all `<a>` tags have `href` attributes. Your `all_links` probably has some `None` values in, which `fnmatch()` can't do regex matching on. This happens because some of those tags were probably being used as named anchors `<a name="whatever">` instead of links.

You could add a guard condition to your list comprehension to make sure these get filtered out.

```
all_links = [link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a') if link.get('href')]
```

Subsequently, you could also do the conditional check on your second comprehension.

```
matched_links = [fnmatch(link, pattern) for link in all_links if link]
```